# Draw graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I'm trying to draw any graph in NetworkX, but get nothing, not even errors:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g1=nx.petersen_graph()
nx.draw(g1)
```

Comment: also make sure you are using an interactive backend.  What does `matplotlib.get_backend()` return?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add to the end:

```
plt.show()
```

---

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g1 = nx.petersen_graph()
nx.draw(g1)
plt.show()
```

When run from an interactive shell where `plt.ion()` has been called, the `plt.show()` is not needed. This is probably why it is omitted in a lot of examples.

If you run these commands from a script (where `plt.ion()` has not been called), the `plt.show()` is needed. `plt.ion()` is okay for interactive sessions, but is [not recommended for scripts](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode).

Comment: show() helped. Thanks for this. I ended up saving figures without show().

Answer (score 5):

in ipython notebook, just type in magic

```
%matplotlib inline
```

or

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily plot with `networkx` graphs using jupyter notebook. See first example.

OR, you can use `Bokeh` to plot graphs, which adds useful features.
The package `holoviews` makes it even simpler to plot a graphs with bokeh. It adds features like automatic highlighting and show of labels while hovering over nodes. However, editing colors etc. seems to be an issue.

```
%pylab inline  
# `pylab notebook`  # for interactive plots

import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv

G=nx.Graph()
ndxs = [1,2,3,4]
G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
G.add_weighted_edges_from( [(1,2,0), (1,3,1) , (1,4,-1) , (2,4,1) , (2,3,-1), (3,4,10) ] ) 
nx.draw(G, nx.spring_layout(G, random_state=100))
```

[image]

And here the example with bokeh and holoview:

```
hv.extension('bokeh')
%opts Graph [width=400 height=400]
padding = dict(x=(-1.1, 1.1), y=(-1.1, 1.1))
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout).redim.range(**padding)
```

[image]

You should give it a try and plot it in your notebook to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine by adding:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

to your code. mine worked fine.