# why networkx.draw() produces nothing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, networkx

I'm new to python and I'm using IPython, I'm starting to learn about NetworkX, but just in the starting point now I'm noticing that networkx.draw() is not working, here is my code:

```
    import networkx as nx
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4])
    nx.draw(g)
```

but nothing is drawn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could show this via PyPlot:
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

NetworkX has some great examples on their website:
https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/auto_examples/index.html

A similar question and answer was posted here: [Draw graph in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212979/draw-graph-in-networkx)

Comment: but again it's not working in ipython notebook!

Comment: wonder if you have managed to solve it? I face the same issue.

Comment: How did you solve this, OP? You marked this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Grace You have to call `plt.show()` after `nx.draw(G)`. Assumes you `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.