# Drawing simple graphs with Python

Tags: python, graph, computer-science, networkx

I am looking to draw graphs in Python (nodes, edges, loops etc; not graphs as in bar charts and the like). I am struggling to find a good cross-platform library for this; would Tkinter or Qt be capable of this? If not are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: networkx and pygraphviz

Answer (score 1):

Networkx is the most used library to generate and analyze networks in python, then I strongly suggest it. Please, take a look at this documentation:

https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating-network-graphs-with-python

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html

[Draw graph in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212979/draw-graph-in-networkx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19887054)

Comment: In this answer I'm just suggesting to use networkx and I'm providing some documentation. Going further would mean to transcend the question and go off topic, in my opinion. Anyway, I'm editing my response to be clearer